# Using separate javascript file for each html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, caching, browser

Usually, the javascripts of the main page is heavier than other pages. For example, we put jQuery slideshow in the main page which is not used in other pages. Is it necessary to create different s for the main and individual pages to include only in-action javacript files?

Or all javascript files read on the first page will be cached for browsing the website, and in loading an indivitual page, browser will not read the javascript of slideshow?

Another form of this question is: if I put slideshow on each individual page, will the browser load the slideshow javascript file each time, or it will read from its cache (saved on the visitor's computer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like florian h says most browsers will cache the content (unless development tools are being used).

if you only use the slideshow javascript on one page I would recommend putting it in a separate file. There is a downside to this, most often the http requests take the longest time with loading a file.

So if you for example have one javascript file of 1mb and you need all the javascript on most pages its better then using 4 smaller files of 250kb each. Because your browser needs to do 4 separate requests.

Ofcourse this maybe is a difference of a couple of milliseconds of performance profit, so you might want to choose to do it in separate files anyway to increase maintainability.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! I am talking about 100kb for jQuery and probably up to 100kb for other jQuery plugins. Obviously jQuery should be on all pages. I was thinking of making a single custom js file for all plugins. Dividing will be for four 25kb. Is it worth of splitting?

Comment: During development I would split, then when the scripts are ready for a production environment a single js file would be best in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Allmost all browsers will cache the javascript files, so you shouldn't create different versions for sub pages.

But if you have very large JS files it's of course reasonable to only include those that you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

All files are cached in the browser based on the path to the file.

If you include an javascript from one page, the file will be cached and it won't be downloaded again when you surf other pages.

Unless you want it to ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, js files will be cached (if not said otherwise).

But, js files must be processed and may include initialization logic that you do not need. Also every script tag that loads external js will block any other "http thread", meaning images, css files... will stop loading untill js file is loaded, otherwise you will have several parallel (at same time) resources loading.

I would have different scripts for different pages.

For your case it might be an issue and it might not be. You should make few test for you case and see whether do you have performance issues. If not than convenience of not having different scripts for different pages might be better.